# SMPP connection failed with smsc using jasmin sms gateway

Tags: python, docker-compose, smpp, jasmin-sms

I am trying to connect to our smsc without success and I don't know why it has this error and I am new to jasmin sms gateway.

I restarted the service and checked the network configuration but still the same error

I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem without result.
Does anyone know the cause and solution please ?

these are the error messages:

```
2023-04-14 10:57:26 INFO     1 Reconnecting after 10 seconds ...
2023-04-14 10:57:36 INFO     1 Connecting to IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='172.xx.xx.xx', port=2775) ...
2023-04-14 10:57:40 ERROR    1 Connection failed. Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>: User timeout caused connection failure.
]
2023-04-14 10:57:40 INFO     1 Reconnecting after 10 seconds ...
2023-04-14 10:57:43 ERROR    1 Connection failed. Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>: User timeout caused connection failure.
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simmilar problem but mine is connection lost.
2023-04-17 08:52:53 ERROR    6494 Connection lost. Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.